# printing comma-separated integer size of directory and contents

Tags: bash, awk

The following will print out the size in bytes of a directory and its contents:

```
ls -lR | grep -v '^d' | awk '{bytes += $5} END {print "Total bytes: " bytes}'
```

The output looks like this:

```
Total bytes: 1088328265
```

How can I most-simply modify my command so that the output has comma-separated numbers, like this:

```
Total bytes: 1,088,328,265
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "Total bytes: %\047d\n", 1088328265}'
Total bytes: 1,088,328,265
```

So puting aside the usual advice to not parse the output of ls and getting rid of the grep since you never need grep when you're using awk, we can make your whole command:

```
ls -lR | awk '!/^d/{bytes += $5} END{printf "Total bytes: %\047d\n", bytes}'
```

`\047` is how to represent a single-quote in a single-quote-delimited awk script and then from [the GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Format-Modifiers):

A single quote or apostrophe character is a POSIX extension to ISO C. It indicates that the integer part of a floating-point value, or the entire part of an integer decimal value, should have a thousands-separator character in it. This only works in locales that support such characters. For example:

```
$ cat thousands.awk          Show source program
-| BEGIN { printf "%'d\n", 1234567 }
$ LC_ALL=C gawk -f thousands.awk
-| 1234567                   Results in "C" locale
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 gawk -f thousands.awk
-| 1,234,567                 Results in US English UTF locale
```

For more information about locales and internationalization issues, see [Locales](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Locales).

Comment: I spoke too soon. 

I'm running Linux Mint XFCE 18.3, built on Ubuntu 16.04

When I run your solution, this is what happens : 

` ls -lR | awk '!/^d/{bytes += $5} END{Total bytes: %\047d\n", bytes}'
`awk: cmd. line:1: !/^d/{bytes += $5} END{Total bytes: %\047d\n", bytes}
`awk: cmd. line:1:                                   ^ syntax error
   `awk: cmd. line:1: !/^d/{bytes += $5} END{Total bytes: %\047d\n", bytes}`awk: cmd. line:1:

Thoughts ?

Comment: The 2nd script in my answer was missing the `printf "` that's in the first script. I fixed that now. That's one of the reason why when you post a question it's best to provide sample input and expected output that we can test against, otherwise you get best-guess but untested answers.

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl instead of awk:

```
perl -lane '$bytes += $F[4];
            END { substr $bytes, -3 * $_, 0, ","
                      for reverse 1 .. (length($bytes)-1)/3;
                  print "Total bytes: $bytes"}'
```

- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to prints
- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits the input on whitespace into the @F array
- [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr) inserts spaces to each position; we use negative positions which count from the right, but we start from the leftmost position so the numbers don't change as we add the commas